# Debugging java applet from c# application

Tags: java, c#

I have a customised error message displaying every time I perform a certain function in a java applet. I am trying to find this error message and the trigger for it. This java applet is inside a c# web application. I have two .jar files. I'm guessing the trick is to look in either of these. The problem is I don't know how to view them.

Whenever I do a search through the solution for the error message nothing comes up.

Comment: try do decompile the jar files, use JDGui: http://jd.benow.ca/

Comment: What is the error message? You say it is a custom error, but if you're new to Java then it's possible that it is a standard (but not common) error message!?

Comment: Hi It is customised. It says "The product selected cannot be assigned to the Category"

Comment: @MihaiC - how do you decompile. I downloaded the Java Development Kit. Still figuring out how to use it.

Comment: @Shahista you have to use 3rd party software. I already linked you to one called JD-GUI, this is the link: http://jd.benow.ca/